# can I multiply delimiter of array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, slice, multiplication

I need to divide the arrays. I have made this code:

```
systemHosts=(here the list on hosts which is around 700 positions)
openSSHlineLimit=1024
systemHostsLength=${#systemHosts[@]}
systemHostsByteLength=$(echo ${systemHosts[@]} | wc -c)
let divideBy=$systemHostsByteLength/$openSSHlineLimit
let modu=$systemHostsByteLength%$openSSHlineLimit
if [[ $divideBy == 0 ]] && [[ $modu != 0 ]]; then
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]}
    user system
        "  #> ~/.ssh/config
elif [[ $divideBy == 1 ]] && [[ $modu > 0 ]]; then
    let getBreak=$systemHostsLength/2
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]::$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # >> ~/.ssh/config
elif [[ $divideBy == 2 ]] && [[ $modu > 0 ]]; then
    let getBreak=$systemHostsLength/3
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]::$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak:$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*2}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
elif [[ $divideBy == 3 ]] && [[ $modu > 0 ]]; then
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]::$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]:($getBreak:$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*3:$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*4}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
elif [[ $divideBy == 4 ]] && [[ $modu > 0 ]]; then
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]::$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*2:$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*3:$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*4:$getBreak}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
    echo "
host   ${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*5}
    user system
        "  # > ~/.ssh/config
fi
```

those parts:

```
${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*2:$getBreak}
${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*3:$getBreak}
${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*4:$getBreak}
```

does not really work
however this

```
${systemHosts[@]:$getBreak*2}
```

works perfectly well

I it that the expression **...[@]:$var*n:$var** is not allowed or I do something wrong?

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.    UPDATE / SOLUTION /
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Hi. I write in here as I blocked answaring for this questin :<
the script did not work because I forgot to add:

```
let getBreak=$systemHostsLength/<divider>
```

on the beginning of each elif :/
Sorry for bothering and thanks a lot for all the answares ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are mixing length in bytes and array size :

```
let divideBy=$systemHostsByteLength/$openSSHlineLimit
let modu=$systemHostsByteLength%$openSSHlineLimit
```

depending on length of names can give different values for divideBy and modulo, and may not execute no if branch.

`$` is not required in arithmetic context:

```
## example
arr=(host-{1..25})
for ((i=0;i<5;i+=1)); do echo ${arr[@]:5*i:5}; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
${systemHosts[@]:getBreak*2:getBreak}
```

should be better (length and offset are arithmetic expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Would you be interested in a paradigma shift?

```
$ echo host{1..25}|fmt -w40|while read line ; do echo "
host $line
    user system
"; done

host host1 host2 host3 host4 host5 host6
    user system


host host7 host8 host9 host10 host11 host12
    user system


host host13 host14 host15 host16 host17
    user system


host host18 host19 host20 host21 host22
    user system


host host23 host24 host25
    user system

$
```

(a width of 40 was chosen to let you count the lengths of the hostnames' sublists, but you can use any width you like.)

Comment: I did actually solved the problem already. Your way is much cleaner and nicer. Thanks a lot

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem … may I ask if you have a policy against upvoting?